# Can the gmail 'default reply behavior' option be set programatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail

In the gmail UI, there is an option to set the 'default reply behavior'. the values are 'Reply' or 'Reply all'. Can this setting (or any other settings on the General Tab of GMail settings) be changed programmatically?

Searched low and high through the Gmail APIs concerning settings, and didn't find these settings. I need conformation.

Comment: Check the [GmailMessage Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) there are methods for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only update a handful of those types of settings via the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings). I don't see reply/reply all listed there, but you can update things like vacation and language settings.